# Rebuilding Slave server from Master

Tags: mysql

I joined my company around 2 months ago. On Monday i saw one of the slave server hard disk blinking amber light and i called Dell for this, the engineer came and said there is no saving the data. The setting is RAID 10, but 2 hard disk failed in the same span and new disk can't be rebuild from the existing ones because both failed. So, Dell engineer inserted 2 new hardisk and wipe the current existing configuration and rebuild a new RAID10.
Anyway, my problem is, this slave server(it's running ubuntu 12.04) has 3 partition,

/ --> root partition (running the usual RAID 1)

/dev/sdb1 --> /var/lib/mysql (this is the disk that failed, now nothing can be read from this)

/dev/sdc1 --> this is an SAN storage connection, containing the data of sql.

Now, i am a purely system guy and haven't had much interaction with mysql(usually there's a dba around and i only troubleshoot stuffs like ports problem or permissions). But the DBA is on holiday until next week.

My question is, how do i rebuild /var/lib/mysql from master without corrupting anything? i did my research and found a few steps, but i would greatly appreciate if there's a real step by step guide(commands and everything) on how i can do this without corrupting anything.

I mean, can i stop both master and slave, rsync /var/lib/mysql from master to slave. On slave changed the permission so that mysql has permission on all folders. Is there anything else i can do to or another steps that i can perform to make sure this goes as smooth as possible? The master can be stop on maintenance window and i have 2 maintenance window coming up. MySQL version running on this is 5.5.40.

Greatly appreciate if there's anyone that can help on this..

Answer (score 1):

I highly recommend using percona's XtraBackup for this.
https://www.percona.com/doc/percona-xtrabackup/LATEST/howtos/setting_up_replication.html

You can combine steps 1 and 2 into a single step, by streaming the backup.

There's a nice write up here
https://www.nadeau.tv/setting-up-a-new-mysql-slave-database-via-streaming-xtrabackup/

There should be no reason to stop the master at any point.